# Icons for two versions of the same iPhone/iPad App

Tags: ios, app-store

I'm try to develop "pro" version of an app which is already at store. As far as I understand I need  a seperate icon for the pro version. Is it possible to change the icon completely? For example instead of typing "pro", can I change the colours of the icon?

A common question: is there any relationship between two versions of the same app? Or are they completely separate apps?

Thank you

Comment: What does this have to do with the `xcode IDE`, `iPad` and `iPhone`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have different icons, you have to separate both apps, they cannot be the same. You'll have to do 2 separated apps in your case.

Comment: I have a different "target" for the pro version, so does it mean that it is completely different app?

Comment: If they have different bundle ID, then yes.

Answer (score 0):

Also, remember, you'll want to upload a different Large icon (iTunes Artwork) file to iTunes Connect. Since that image, not the icon file inside the app bundle, is what your potential customers will see.